# Patterns for AngularJS to update view in controller during recursive HTTP GET

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion, model-view-controller

Using AngularJS I have a historicalDataController

```
angular.module('armsApp').controller('historicalDataController', ($scope, $historicalFactory) => {
  $scope.histogram = new Histogram('#histogram');

  historicalFactory.getHistorycalData().then((data) => {
    $scope.histogram.update(data);
  });
});
```

and historicalFactory

```
angular.module('armsApp').factory('historicalFactory', ['$q', '$http',

  function ($q, $http) {

    return {

      getHistoricalData() {
        const deferred = $q.defer();

        function loadAll(page) {
          const token = cognito.getToken('id');
          // let deferred = $q.defer();

          return $http({
            // details
          })
            .then((response) => {

              if (response.data.pages > page) {
                loadAll(page + 1);
              } else {
                deferred.resolve(response.data);
              }
            });
        }
        loadAll(0);
        return deferred.promise;
      },
```

The former manages my D3 histogram element and the latter handles communication to my data server.

From historicalDataController I am initiating a call to a function in historicalFactory which using recursion does serial GETs to a paginated REST endpoint and aggregates the data. In the controller I currently update the D3 histogram when the function returns with the full dataset, which functions OK.

Now I want to incrementally update the histogram with results from each GET but the callbacks are in the factory which has no access to the UI element (and I feel like view-related logic does not belong in there).

What are some good options of patterns to use here?

From factory should I write the incremental data to a variable in controller and broadcast an event to controller? This feels messy somehow.

Could I use some kind of cross-module decorator to wrap the Histogram-update function with the recursive GET function?

Comment: Use of `$q.defer` with a promise based service such as `$http` is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), an indication of a deeper problem. In this case the `$q.defer` never resolves if a `$http` request has an error. To write an answer, I would need to know more about the data. What is `data.pages`? And how does it change with each `$http` call?

Comment: I would suggest that you try to get it to work in a controller first. Then figure how to put it in a service.

Comment: What would `loadAll(0)` return? What would `loadAll(1)` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the "notification" callback to provide updates on a promise without resolving it. When one of your `$http` calls resolves, call `deferred.notify()`. In your controller, you'll want to provide "catch" and "notifiy" callbacks in your `.then()`.

See the full documentation of $q.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q